# Trying to make a standalone executable file of a flask application using pyinstaller

Tags: python, flask, nltk, exe, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to make a standalone executable version of  flask app. On running the created executable file a fatal error popup is shown which states

```
**"Failed to execute script pyi_rth_nltk"**
Failed to load dynlib/dll 
'C:\\Users\\anolk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI58202\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomps140.dll'. 
Mostly probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen
```

I create the executable file by running the following command:

pyinstaller -w --onefile --add-data "static;static" --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "models;models" app.py

My directory has the following structure:

```
/app
  /models
  /static
  /templates
  app.py
  pythonfile1.py
  pythonfile2.py
```

Comment: By searching using a popular search engine for nothing more complicated than __pyinstaller flask__ I found this which appears to relate to getting pyinstaller to work with flask. https://github.com/ciscomonkey/flask-pyinstaller/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I am pretty new to coding, I have added models, static and templates folder while initialising app as shown below. Am i also supposed to add all the individual files ?


```app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_folder, static_folder=static_folder,models_folder=models_folder)```

Comment: Ah you've added more detail of the error - that is pyinstaller not playing well with nltk - tried searching using a popular search engine for something no more complicated than __pyinstaller nltk__ (get the theme?) and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128735/using-pyinstaller-with-nltk-results-in-error-cant-find-nltk-data then this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3799 which leads to this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/3900/files which seems to be included in pyinstaller developer stream, don't know if it's in a stable build yet. Good luck!

Comment: I did use a popular search engine, I just didnt wanna seem rude. :D This is not the issue I have described above, I already got the issue you have referenced in the links above and solved it using those links themself.

Comment: My issue is it says failed to execute script pyi_rth_nltk. On googling it said something about Two underscores in the name of the script and I crosschecked it and it is all fine. If you could provide more insight into this issue Id be really thankful.

Comment: Ay use? https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4648

Comment: @barny They havent found a solution yet on that link, I'll keep an eye on that. Please let me know if you get any other leads.